# Tag for questions about changing the nature of words

Tags: support, tags

There are ways for converting between noun and verb (e.g. noun -> verb by adding -suru, and verb -> noun by dropping the ending of the verb), turning adjectives into adverbs, etc. I could not find a tag for this sort of conversion. (But as the clumsy title of this question hints, I don't quite know how it may be called.)

Comment: There's at least [tag:nominalization] for "making something into a noun" but not "verbing" and the rest.

Comment: @AndrewT. In [this case](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65447/), it can go both ways noun <-> verb, so it would require a more generic tag.

Comment: More generally, *derivation*.  For example, the verb ググる is *derived from* グーグル via a regular process; the noun 話 is *derived from* the 連用形 of the verb 話す, which is 話し.